# Simplify sum of sum queries in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables that follow a reimbursement request from its costing phase to its invoicing phase, recording line items and their values at each stage of the request.

To get the totals for each expense category at each phase, I summed them using a select - what I have not been able to figure out is an efficient way to sum their grand totals for the entire phase without having to doing another sum request. Since this queries hundreds of thousands of rows - the response time is suffering. The current method takes just under 4.59 seconds - while when I remove the grand total sums it takes 4.02 seconds - any advice on how to alias the original sums to get a grand total would be most welcome:

```
SELECT p.program_name, p.id as program_id, p.entity_id, a.id as account_id,


(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 9 and c.account_id = a.id) as NIPLoanCost,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 2 and c.account_id = a.id) as AcquisitionCost,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 3 and c.account_id = a.id) as PreDemoCost,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 4 and c.account_id = a.id) as DemolitionCost,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 5 and c.account_id = a.id) as GreeningCost,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 6 and c.account_id = a.id) as MaintenanceCost,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 7 and c.account_id = a.id) as AdministrationCost,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 8 and c.account_id = a.id) as OtherCost,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE c.account_id = a.id) 
as TotalCost,

/* I have removed the other 4 table's requests that follow this same methodology */

FROM programs p, accounts a  WHERE p.entity_id = a.entity_id;
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `a.entity_id` and `a.id` ?

Comment: Entity (entity_id) is the organization that owns the account (a.id) to which the items belong. An entity may own many accounts, but an account can only have one entity.

Comment: I gave you an answer below, which you may have to slightly modify.

Comment: Sorry let me further clarify: @TimBiegeleisen Entity (entity_id) is the organization that owns the account (a.id) to which the items belong. An entity may own many accounts, but an account can only have one entity. An entity also may own many programs, but a program may only belong to one entity. Thus a program can have line items that each use a different account owned by the entity. Fun right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with a join to the `cost_items` table to replace all the subqueries.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT p.program_name,
       p.id as program_id,
       p.entity_id,
       t.*
FROM programs p
INNER JOIN accounts a
    ON p.entity_id = a.entity_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.id AS account_id,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.expense_category_id = 9 THEN c.amount ELSE 0 END) AS NIPLoanCost,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.expense_category_id = 2 THEN c.amount ELSE 0 END) AS AcquisitionCost,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.expense_category_id = 3 THEN c.amount ELSE 0 END) AS PreDemoCost,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.expense_category_id = 4 THEN c.amount ELSE 0 END) AS DemolitionCost,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.expense_category_id = 5 THEN c.amount ELSE 0 END) AS GreeningCost,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.expense_category_id = 6 THEN c.amount ELSE 0 END) AS MaintenanceCost,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.expense_category_id = 7 THEN c.amount ELSE 0 END) AS AdministrationCost,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.expense_category_id = 8 THEN c.amount ELSE 0 END) AS OtherCost,
           COALESECE(SUM(c.amount), 0) AS TotalCost
    FROM accounts a
    LEFT JOIN cost_items c
        ON a.id = c.account_id
    GROUP BY a.id
) t
    ON a.id = t.account_id
```

Note that the flaw with your original approach was correlated subqueries like this one:

```
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE expense_category_id = 9 and c.account_id = a.id)
```

For every record in the joined product of the `programs` and `accounts` table you were issuing a separate query (many of them actually) which was scanning the entire `cost_items` table to determine the sum.  In my approach, we make a single pass through the join of `accounts` and `cost_items`, and this is where the time is saved.

Comment: Wow... let me try and see.

Comment: Looks like the ON a.id = t.id should be ON a.id = t.account_id - making that change - it does give me the totals very fast (.05 sec) - but I am not seeing how to get the grand total of all the items together

Comment: If you want anything more complex than this, then you should really clean up your question and add sample data, with expected output.

Comment: Thanks Tim - the portion of the original query I am referring to is the : `(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM cost_items c WHERE c.account_id = a.id) 
as TotalCost` - all the other totals in your example work brilliantly - WAY more efficient - just wasn't sure if there was a way to get that total by adding up the previous sum queries rather than make another. - so the output would have the additional column of TotalCost that is the total of all the items for that account.

Comment: So when I add in the total for the entire set (not limited to a category): `COALESCE(SUM(c.amount),0) AS TotalCost` to the SELECT, the impact is imperceptible (still .05 seconds) - is it ok if I edit your answer to show the changes and credit it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @BrianGreenwood I made that change, I guessed I missed something.  Note that using `COALESCE` on the other terms isn't necessary, because the `CASE` expression will always assign either zero or an amount.

Comment: Can't thank you enough - insanely faster and opened my eyes on better consolidation. I have never used the case method before and admittedly struggle on when to use inner and left joins - this is a great example of how their utilization can dramatically impact processing time down to just 1.08% of its previous speed. WOW.

Comment: @BrianGreenwood I added a bit of an explanation at the end of my answer.  In your original approach, which may have been logically correct, you were using _correlated_ subqueries to compute the totals.  "Correlated" means that for _every_ outer record, MySQL was doing a separate query, for each total.  This can be a real performance killer when working with larger data sets.